# Android Get contacts in Custom View only

Tags: android, contacts

Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, Android 6.0.1, Microsoft Exchange Active Sync.

I have a custom view for my contacts that is restricted to Exchange (Outlook) main contacts only. There is also an Achived Contacts list which is not included in the custom view. On the phone contacts I only see the main list which is what I want

In my app I query the contact database for a person and it works ok. However, I also get people from the Achived Contacts.

```
String partial = "Henry"
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(partial));
Cursor nameCursor = contentResolver.query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
if (nameCursor != null)
{
 ...
```

I get Henrys from both the archived list and from the main list. How do I restrict the search to the main list only?

Comment: Please try to include the ACCOUNT_TYPE filter in the selection part. Something like this: ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE="name"

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround although there must be a more elegant approach:

```
int visible = nameCursor.getInt(nameCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP));
if (visible > 0)
{
 ...
```